# New Year vs. new year

Tags: capitalization

On Jan 7, I wrote to a native speaker and wished her a great new year, but I used the capitalized form:

> I wish you a very prosperous New Year.

Now I'm in doubt if it's at all meaningful considering that the new year has actually begun.

Could anyone please advise? Was that a right form?

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker, I find that it is very common for people to wish each other a "Happy New Year"  well into most of January, especially if it is the first time that they have seen each other since Decemeber 31st.  I hear this in conversation all the time, and I see it, written exactly as you have written it, often as well.

I am not sure if  you are also asking if it is correct to write
"Happy New Year" instead of "Happy new year".
If that is part of your question, then I would say that because it has become sort of a stylized traditional greeting, that your usage was correct.  It is written that way all of the time, in the same way we say the following:

- Merry Christmas
- Happy Thanksgiving
- Happy Valentine's Day
- Happy St.    Patrick's Day
- Happy Memorial Day

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and helpful response. I Googled my question (capitalize new year) before mentioning it here and got the following answer. That is why I felt I had probably used a wrong phrase: "And if you are referring to the holiday, it is capitalized: New Year's Day. But if you are simply referring to next year, it is not: in the new year. (Although "Happy New Year!" is standard.) In December 2005, I wrote message templates for New Year's...